# how do i total the sum from datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

-how do i get the sum of totalPrice in my datagridview from mysql

```
ProductName          Qty.   Price    totalPrice
2 Pcs. Chickenjoy     5      59         295
2 Pcs. Chickenjoy     1      69          69
2 Pcs. Chickenjoy     1      69          59

                                  TOTAL??
```

-the sum should be 423 the problem is,  it will double the sum

-here's my code:

```
Try
    'declaring variable as integer to store the value of the total rows in the datagridview

    Dim max As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim total As String = "Total ----------->"
    'getting the values of a specific rows


    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        'formula for adding the values in the rows
        DataGridView1.Rows(max).Cells(4).Value += row.Cells(4).Value
        DataGridView1.Rows(max).Cells(3).Value = total
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Screenshots
http://goo.gl/Ufj53b

Comment: set a break point and watch the code execute.  you will learn a lot about the difference between what you think code will do and what it actually does AND learn how to use the debugger

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim tot As Integer
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    'formula for adding the values in the rows
    tot += row.Cells(4).Value
Next
DataGridView1.Rows(max).Cells(3).Value = total
DataGridView1.Rows(max).Cells(4).Value = tot
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem appears to be using a For Each loop.  When it reaches the last row it's adding the accumulated total to itself.  A For loop to only the second last row should work:

```
Try
    'declaring variable as integer to store the value of the total rows in the datagridview

    Dim max As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    'getting the values of a specific rows
    DataGridView1.Rows(max).Cells(3).Value = "Total ----------->"

    For I = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
        'formula for adding the values in the rows
        DataGridView1.Rows(max).Cells(4).Value += DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(4).Value
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: big thanks to you sir @tinstaafl
one last question and help
how do i send the sum in textbox1.text from datagridview, im sorry im new in datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

your loop has an error. because it will count the sum of 295,69 and 59 then that added to the sum again. thats why it will double the sum. try this

```
Try
    'declaring variable as integer to store the value of the total rows in the datagridview

    Dim max As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim total As String = "Total ----------->"
    Dim tot as integer =0 
    'getting the values of a specific rows


    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        'formula for adding the values in the rows
        tot += row.Cells(4).Value
    Next
    DataGridView1.Rows(max).Cells(4).Value += tot
        DataGridView1.Rows(max).Cells(3).Value = total
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```